# React-navigation tabnavigator reloads on parents state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the tabnavigator from react navigation.  I have a parent component that looks like this

```
changeService(serviceName){
 this.setState({

 });
}

render() {
const { container } = styles
return (
<View style={container}>
  <Header
  clientName = {this.state.project}
  serviceName = {this.state.service}
  cancelClick = {this.handleExitClick}
  />
  <ServicesNavigator
  changeService = {this.changeService}
  />
</View>
);
}
```

Then my service navigator export looks like this

```
export default (props) => {
 const { screenProps, ...otherProps } = props;
 const ServicesNavigator = makeServiceNavigator(props);
 return <ServicesNavigator screenProps={{ ...screenProps, ...otherProps 
 }} />
};
```

The navigator itself looks like a normal navigator except it hsa navigationOptions equal to

```
tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
    changeService(scene.scene.route.routeName)
    scene.jumpToIndex(scene.scene.index)
  },
```

Whenever i try to change tabs the navigator is reloading completely and going back to default tab selection.  Is there no way to allow the tabnavigors parents state variables to change without reseting the tab navigator?

Comment: I think it can't. You should store the states and then render base on them.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever `tabBarOnPress` is triggered, it requests to update state of the parent component. Then due to React component lifecycle, state update will cause parent component to re-render, along with all its children. This is why your tab navigator is reseted all the times.

There are several solutions for your case:

1 - Use `shouldComponentUpdate` to guide when parent component to be updated. Since you want to retain `ServicesNavigator` whenever `changeService` is called, you want to avoid re-rendering on related state items.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.itemA !== nextState.itemA) {
        return false; // avoid re-rendering
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is dirty but working; however it will haunt you in the long run since it causes parent component's behaviours not idempotent.

**Edit:** I forgot you have the `Header` which reads the state. If you use `shouldComponentUpdate` in the parent component, then `Header` will not receive new props. So 1st option is not correct. Sorry about this.

2 - Don't let parent component hold the state anymore. In your sample code, parent component has state only because its children components need to communicate and share data with each others. So why don't you just keep the sharing data somewhere else? Best tools can be state management libraries like `mobx` or `redux`, which can be integrated quite easily with `react-navigation`

Comment: Thanks the problem with shouldParentUpdate is that i need parent to update so that header can update when state changes, i just need the navigator to not update.  The problem with adding mobx or redux is simply that i have a crunch deadline and am trying to avoid learning something new until i get it out :).  
I wonder if it would be best to make the navigator into a pure class component, not ideal as i prefer to use functional components and then have a look at redux next week.

Comment: @AdamKatz updated my answer. Sorry to say but the 1st option does not solve your case. You might need to research further to do it in React way.